# Elasticsearch - how to extract date from date time field and add it to each document as a new field

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am learning elasticssearch and in one of the demo databases given to me, i have a date time field saved with the name time_stamp.  The date data is saved as text:

```
"time_stamp":"13-06-2019 04:44:23"
```

I want to create a new data field titled "date" and extract only the date from each document and store it within the same document. The current index mapping is as follows:

```
{
    "vp1": {
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
                "client_id": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "encod": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "imagename": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "indx": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "machid": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "matchid": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "sequence_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "time_stamp": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using python3 to interact with the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to update your mapping in order to add the new field since the `dynamic` setting is set to false the new field cannot be created automatically:

```
PUT vp1/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, an easy way to achieve what you want is to do it like this:

```
POST vp1/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.date = /\\s/.split(ctx._source.time_stamp)[0]"
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks...when I paste the above code on kibana, I get an error indicating `bad string`.  I ran the code from terminal as CURL and got the error `error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unrecognized character escape 's' (code 115)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@772237c8; line: 4, column: 38]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unrecognized character escape 's' (code 115)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@772237c8; line: 4, column: 38]"},"status":500}`

Comment: Oops, please try again, I missed one escape character

Comment: thank you again...when I ran the code got this error `"cause":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [date] tried to parse field [date] as object, but found a concrete value"},"status":400}]}`

Comment: That means you already have a field named `date` in your index. Can you show what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/vp1` and also the ES version you're running?

Comment: i think I made a mistake the output is: `{"vp1":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"dynamic":"false","properties":{"client_id":{"type":"text"},"date":{"properties":{"date":{"type":"date"}}},"encod":{"type":"float"},"imagename":{"type":"text"},"indx":{"type":"text"},"machid":{"type":"text"},"matchid":{"type":"float"},"sequence_id":{"type":"integer"},"time_stamp":{"type":"text"}}},"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":"5","provided_name":"vp1","max_result_window":"100000","creation_date":"1561486804831","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"-7f7GBFFTB2ACbxupXj-kQ","version":{"created":"7010199"}}}}}`

Comment: @val...i think I made a mistake while adding the date field

Comment: Yes, your date field is not correct, indeed. Either create another field correctly or reindex your data

Comment: no...i have gotten into a bigger mess with elasticsearch as I work more....kind of reworking the entire analysis...will keep you posted

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I took time to respond, as I have to recreate the entire setup owing to multiple gaps that I had between ES and my data.